# Powershell GUI displaying text file

Tags: forms, powershell, user-interface

I have an app I developed and made a GUI for. In one of the directories I have a `log.txt` file.
I have a strip menu option meant to display the log file to the user. I'm wondering what would be the best method for displaying this log file?

Right now I'm just using

`notepad log.txt`

Which technically works but doesn't seem to be the most efficient or professional way.

I'm guessing it is probably just opening another form with a large read only text box but on the off chance someone has something that works even better I'll appreciate the suggestion.

Info displayed in log is:

1. Version
2. Description
3. Date

Comment: A `TextBox` seems good for your use case, you probably want to set it's `Enabled` property to `$false`

Comment: With you being as knowledgeable as you are would it be un kosher if I was to ask you to look at my app and possibly just give me general advice on optimizing it? Keeping in mind I have not implemented the error handling functions.